# What is the "best" way to sample a function?

Tags: computer-science, signal-processing, sampling, monte-carlo, sampling-theory

## The situation

Imagine that you are faced with a box with a numeric display and a knob next to it that can turn in specific increments (that you can specify) and in both directions (increasing values or decreasing values).

Each time you turn the knob in any direction you see the value associated with this knob position and the output (the value on the numeric display).

## The questions

Given the above situation, imagining that the box encodes a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ that you have no a priori information about (you acquire knowledge about the function by sampling it), if you are given a finite number of points (for example to plot the graph of this function) over a given interval $I = [a, b] \text{ where } (a<b)$ :

1. What is the "best" (see note) way to sample this function ("box") on $I$ if you can only turn the knob in one direction (imagine that it is because a phenomenon like [backlash](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Backlash_(engineering)) is at work) starting at the start of the interval, $a$ ?
2. Are there algorithms to deal with this problem ? If not, why ? Uniform sampling exists but seem not "optimized".
3. Imagine that you can afford to make multiple passes to refine your estimates of the function, what is the best strategy to put your sampling points on each passes (that are still unidirectional: you can only go to $a$ when you reached $b$) ? Are the strategies dependent on the number of passes ?
4. Is there any extension to higher dimensions to any of the previous solutions ?

Note: I do understand that the characteristics of best change given the metric used to qualify it (spectrum sampling, variation, etc). Answers on any of them would be enlightening so I remain blurry on the term.

Bonus question :

- What is the domain of science that deals with this kind of questions ? It seems like the sampling area of signal processing but I can not find any relevant answers... Being able to name a problem is already starting to solving it. Pointers appreciated !

Comment: There are a lot of smooth functions.  Indeed, given a finite collection of values, there are infinitely many polynomials that pass through all of them.  If we have "no a priori knowledge" then there is no way to distinguish between these.  Which one of those polynomials is more "optimal" than another?  And who said the answer was even polynomial?

Comment: I totally agree with you but it seems to me intuitively that one is acquiring information about the sampled function each time they sample so can get a better approach to the sampling and that is the underlying question.

Comment: There are a lot of smooth functions.  You need an a priori metric to tell you which interpolating function is more probable than another.

Comment: You may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes

Comment: @Milten That is very interesting indeed!

Comment: The question as stated is much too broad and does not allow specific answers beyond general links to Wikipedia articles and textbooks on approximation theory.

Comment: I am not entirely sure of your conclusion : 
1. You did not try to even cite the said textbooks nor Wikipedia articles
2. If resources exists why not share them instead of negatively bashing the questioner ?
3. If you are so sure that question is not worth anyone's time why are you answering ? Why not just flag it to the moderators and let them take care of it ?

I took my time to outline to you @gg that I think that answers of this kind should not be the ones you take because it breeds toxic communities where people just do not want to ask questions. Flag the moderators. Stop bashing.

Comment: I did not bash, I just told you my opinion, maybe even the facts. Ad 1) and 2) Since your post was so broad it is not clear what information may actually help you. So why waste yours or anyone else's time? Furthermore, you already received one link to Wikipedia, which may (or may not?) be pertinent. And did you follow up on my suggestion and had a look at "approximation theory"? Ad 3) I actually wanted to explain to you why you have received ZERO answers and NO upvote. Finally, would a a flag to moderators have helped you? Please, don't feel bashed, just improve your question.